# react native app - getting error app.js cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

Tags: ios, react-native, jestjs, expo

well i am not getting any answers to this error .. 
npm update to latest and downgrade also tried.
nothing works
package.json so it i get some help ...

```
{
  "name": "kelsnew",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "^1.14.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^28.0.0",
    "jest": "^23.4.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried several things and several things in combination, but ultimately when I added @babel to my .babelrc plugin line without any other changes. I then deleted `node_modules`, `package-lock.json` and ran `npm install`.

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["@babel/transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  }
}
```

I also upgraded from Nodejs 8 to 10 along the way (and stayed there). I don't think it material, but I mention it just in case, check your `node --version`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your app.js for any calls to the property filename such as `someObject.filename`, this is most likely due to some object not being instantiated and thus you are getting `undefined.filename` which throws an error.

Comment: well its not that..i try to make another project from scratch and getting errors ..

Comment: @JayanaSoneji hmmmm... can you edit your original post to include the `app.js` file so I can take a look?